# Excel VBA to insert sheet name on each row when combining data tables with variable columns

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have code which nicely copies data from multiple sheets in a workbook to a summary sheet and the variable number of sheets have always contained data in exactly the same format.

The input files now have a variable number of columns (roughly 50% exactly the same and 50% variable) and I now need to extend the code so that the sheet name is added to the data copied to the summary sheet.  I can then copy the fixed-format data onto the summary sheet and use part of that, along with the sheet name, to reference the variable data and copy it into the necessary column.

The current code is below and I would be grateful if someone could assist with adding a column and the sheet name.  Copying the variable data in once I have the sheet name will be straightforward.

```
 Sub CopyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

Set wsSummary = Worksheets("Summary")

LastRow = wsSummary.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

wsSummary.Range("A2:R" & LastRow).Clear

ShtCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For i = 2 To ShtCount

Worksheets(i).Activate
LastRow2 = activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:R" & LastRow2).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("Summary").Activate

LastRow2 = activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Select

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored the code a little to make it a bit better - Here's how it works:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowWs As Long
    Dim LastRowSummary As Long
    Dim StartRowSummary As Long
    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    LastRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsSummary.Range("A2:R" & LastRowSummary).Clear
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
            LastRowWs = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            StartRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'first empty row
            ws.Range("A2:R" & LastRowWs).Copy Destination:=wsSummary.Range("A" & StartRowSummary) 
            LastRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            wsSummary.Range("S" & StartRowSummary & ":S" & LastRowSummary) = ws.Name
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As you can see it's fairly similar initially, but I have stripped out all the `.Select`, `.Activate` etc commands as they're not needed and can slow down a script during execution.  I've also fully qualified all worksheet references to make sure we always know what part of the workbook we're referring to.

LastRowSummary is set initially to the last row plus 1.  This is simply to ensure that if you only have headers in the summary sheet, you won't delete those.

The `For Each` loop allows us to iterate for every worksheet `ws` in the workbook.

We don't want to extract data from "Summary" so don't carry out the commands for that sheet.

Find the last row in the A column from whatever worksheet we're on, and detect where on the Summary sheet it's going to start from (important when we're going to be setting the worksheet name later on).

Copy the range from one worksheet to the other.  Now get the updated last row for the Summary sheet as this tells us how many rows we need to tag for the worksheet name we copied from.

Since we have a handy reference to the worksheet in `ws`, we can just set column `S` to the `ws.Name`, using the start and end rows we detected earlier to ensure the name is set on all the rows (I've used column S because you only seemed to be copying A to R; S is just the next column; adjust as required for where you want the worksheet name to go).

And finally, remember to switch the `Application.ScreenUpdating` back on.  Though since this version doesn't use the `.Select` or `.Activate`, you won't be flicking between sheets and so you could just drop both the False and True setting of this property without any negative result.

Let me know if you need any further explanation?

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've made a couple of minor edits to remove the formatting from the individual sheets being copied and to move the paste destination down a row, as this was overlapping the ranges.

Comment: Good catch, I've edited the answer to add a row to select the first empty row to start from...