# Code to help consolidate last column used across multiple tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of spreadsheets we use to load parameters into a database for a point and click style of order entry. Some of the spreadsheets have hundreds of sheets and keeping them up to date is constantly a problem. What I am trying to do is insert some code that will go sheet by sheet and compile some data from each tab on to a summary sheet.

I have tinkered with editing the code from [Excel VBA to insert sheet name on each row when combining data tables with variable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707622/excel-vba-to-insert-sheet-name-on-each-row-when-combining-data-tables-with-varia) but I am a total hack and so far have been unsuccessful.

To be brief, I am needing the code to return the sheet name in column A and then scan the first row for the first unused column, then return the contents of that column to column C and the row# it came from to column B on the summary sheet.

[image]

This sample illustrates how the data is structured, a series of questions with an answer at the end. They are not static, but the questions have headers in Row 1 (sometimes just a space value) but the answers do not, Cell 1 of that column is always blank (null).

[image]

EDIT: Using several sources here on Stack Overflow, I have managed to piece this together which almost works. Instead of finding the last used column and row, I need to find the first column with a null header (row 1) and the last row before any breaks. This is due to there being notes added to most sheets on the right of the data and possibly below.

```
Sub CopyData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowWs As Long
    Dim LastColWs As Long
    Dim LastRowSummary As Long
    Dim StartRowSummary As Long
    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary") ' defines WsSummary
    LastRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' identifys the last used row on target summary sheet
    wsSummary.Range("A2:ZZ" & LastRowSummary).Clear 'clears a set range on target summary sheet
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case Ws.Name
            Case "Summary", "Category", "TOC", "Index"
                'If it's one of these sheets, do nothing
            Case Else
            LastRowWs = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Finds the last column in worksheet
            LastColWs = Ws.Cells(LastRowWs, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Finds the last used colun in Worksheet - ISSUE, I need first null cell column!
            StartRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'first empty row
            Ws.Range(Split(Cells(, LastColWs).Address, "$")(1) & "2:" & Split(Cells(, LastColWs).Address, "$")(1) & LastRowWs).Copy Destination:=wsSummary.Range("A" & StartRowSummary)
            LastRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            wsSummary.Range("B" & StartRowSummary & ":B" & LastRowSummary) = Ws.Name ' returns sheet name
            wsSummary.Range("C" & StartRowSummary & ":C" & LastRowSummary) = LastColWs 'returns column #
            wsSummary.Range("D" & StartRowSummary & ":D" & LastRowSummary) = Split(Cells(, LastColWs).Address, "$")(1) 'returns Column letter
        End Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, show us what you tried on your own. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I will edit my original post.

Comment: Your code does not match the description of what you want to do?  Eg. sheet name in ColB vs ColA, source Row# vs source Col#...  In general a lot of confusion between "row" and "column" which makes it hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out - split up the logic a bit to make it a little easier to follow...

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowWs As Long
    Dim LastColWs As Long
    Dim LastRowSummary As Long
    Dim StartRowSummary As Long, copyRange As Range, nextRow As Long
    Dim copyRows As Long, colLetter, ws As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary") ' defines WsSummary
    LastRowSummary = wsSummary.Cells(wsSummary.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsSummary.Range("A2:ZZ" & LastRowSummary).Clear 'clears a set range on target summary sheet
    
    nextRow = 2                              'start pasting here
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ProcessThisSheet(ws) Then         'use this sheet ?
            Set copyRange = GetCopyRange(ws) 'find something to copy
            If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
                copyRows = copyRange.Cells.Count
                colLetter = Split(copyRange.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0), ":")(0)
                With wsSummary.Rows(nextRow)
                    copyRange.Copy .Cells("A")
                    .Columns("B").Resize(copyRows).Value = ws.Name
                    .Columns("C").Resize(copyRows).Value = copyRange.Column
                    .Columns("C").Resize(copyRows).Value = colLetter
                End With
                nextRow = nextRow + copyRows
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'find the range of cells to copy from (returns Nothing if no suitable range located)
Function GetCopyRange(ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim c As Range, c2 As Range, rv As Range
    Set c = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1) 'cell below the empty header cell
    If c.Column = 2 Or Len(c.Value) = 0 Then Exit Function 'on Col2 so row1 was empty, or no value below the empty header
    If Len(c.Offset(1, 0).Value) > 0 Then
        Set GetCopyRange = ws.Range(c, c.End(xlDown)) 'down to end of data
    Else
        Set GetCopyRange = c 'just 1 cell to copy
    End If
End Function

'work with `ws` ?
Function ProcessThisSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Summary", "Category", "TOC", "Index"
            ProcessThisSheet = False
        Case Else
            ProcessThisSheet = True
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Tim, I appreciate your reply! Sorry for the original code being 'messy', I know enough to be dangerous when coding. I tend to have a need and then teach myself what I need to know as I am trying to complete the task, then go back to my 11 other jobs. :) Your code runs through without returning anything to the summary page then crashes on `If c.Column = 2 Or Len(c.Value) = 0 Then Exit Function` of the GetCopyRange function. Is there a way for me to send you one of my actual spreadsheets?

Comment: Sent you a sample at gmail dot com

Comment: Zipped it and resent

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making your Tables, Tables and relating them?

If you are combining data that has ID relationships even if they are across thousands of sheets, you can just make them properly headered Tables with the Insert tab, Related them in the Data tab and then bring them together in Power Pivot/Query, once done you can litterally do a get last row on the Power Query and boom you are done no code, or one better link to that Power Pivoted Table as a table instance and get your system to grab the last row or rows (Just change the number).

```
  SELECT TOP 1 FROM tblResult ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately editing the existing sheets isnt an option. There is a macro built into the spreadsheets that loads all the specifically formatted data into an area of our database for the creation of the point and click system.

Comment: You can reference existing data as a data source, without actually touching it.  once loaded into a consolidated sheet, you can form the relationships and do your metrics :)

I mean the macros are nice for systems but the real power is ETL hit refresh and have them all just load up from their connections without actually opening anything.